# How to compare database value with javascript value.?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel-7

I want to compare lastResult value with database qr code value, if both match redirect to a page else show error. My database is phpmyadmin. I'm using laravel 7 but doing this with html and javascript.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>QR Code Scanner</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/html5-qrcode"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <div id="qr-reader" style="width:500px"></div><br>
    <div id="qr-reader-results" style="padding:10px"></div>


    <script>
        var resultContainer = document.getElementById('qr-reader-results');
        var lastResult, result, countResults = 0;
      
        function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
            if (decodedText !== lastResult) {
                ++countResults;
                lastResult = decodedText;
                // Handle on success condition with the decoded message.
                // console.log (`Scan result ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
                document.getElementById("qr-reader-results").innerHTML=  lastResult;
            }
        }
      
        var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
            "qr-reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
        html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL databases. Your application connects to MySQL directly and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: The flow you need; Your JS code needs to make an Ajax request to your backend, containing all the data it needs. Your backend can then either compare the values directly, or you can return a value to your JS (you'll get it in the response for your Ajax request) so you can compare it. However, if it's about security, the comparing should happen in the backend so you can set the appropriate sessions and only return success/fail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks M. Eriksson. I found the solution. It is done without ajax request.

```
function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
        if (decodedText !== lastResult) {
            ++countResults;
            lastResult = decodedText;
            // Handle on success condition with the decoded message.
            // console.log (`Scan result ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
            // document.getElementById("qr-reader-results").innerHTML=  lastResult;
            if(lastResult == "{{ auth()->user()->qrcode }}"){
                alert("matched");
                location.href="/home";
            }else{
                alert("unmatched");
            }
        }
    }
```